# getting json data from web and list them in android

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-volley

i am developing an android app which can stream / download media from a web server, the first thing i am about to do is getting media on server to be viewed in a list just like Youtube, my problem is that i am inexperienced with Json i saw other posts here about that topic but didn't get me anywhere.
where can i start for simple json toturials to simulate my problem? and i heard about Android Volley for such things in android? how useful is it and shall i work with or without it for now?

Comment: Json is very simple google it you can under stand very easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links may help you to build concept of JSON
You must google rather than asking

in java there is JSONObject, JSONArray, and others to use with it

http://www.json.com/

http://www.w3schools.com/json/

http://www.json.org/